# What the reasons for/against returning 0 from main in ISO C++?

Tags: c++

I know that the C++ standard says that `return 0` is inserted at the end of `main()` if no return statement is given; however, I often see recently-written, standard-conforming C++ code that explicitly returns 0 at the end of `main()`. For what reasons would somebody want to explicitly return 0 if it's automatically done by the compiler?

Comment: Oh, the mysteries of main().  Surely it is because a good programmer doesn't assume that this rule should force him to treat main() different from 99.99% of the other code he writes.  She included.

Comment: Hm, never thought about it like that. I guess it's sort of similar to leaving off function return types in C; I always thought that was sort of shady.

Comment: I don't write `return 0;` on principle unless non-zero is a valid return value.  It makes me feel like a rebel.

Comment: So, the accepted answer is "it just looks weird"? That pretty much proves that this is a totally subjective question.

Comment: @gnovice Are you saying it doesn't look weird?

Comment: @gnovice Well, it's the most applicable answer, I think. The non-conforming compiler answer is perhaps more factual, but I'd say that most of the code I was referring to was written by people using recent, standard compilers, making that answer less applicable.

Comment: @asveikau: I'm saying that "weird" is a subjective value judgment.

Comment: @Maulrus: I find it very telling that you would pass up the "more factual" answer in favor of the one based completely on opinion.

Comment: @gnovice: It's not as applicable in the sense that my question was talking about recent code which is more often than not written for a compiler such as VC++ or g++.

Comment: @gnovice - My comment was a bit concise because I was attempting to be a bit humorous.  My point was that subjective-sounding judgments like "weird" are sometimes rather *objectively* so.  I think the percentage of programmers who would agree with this judgment is fairly high.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it just looks weird to not "return" something from a function having a non-void return type (even if the standard says it's not strictly necessary).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but as I remember the standard says it is strictly necessary.

Comment: @Sergio: If the end of a non-void function is reached without a return statement, it leads to undefined behavior. However, main implicitly will `return 0;`.

Answer (score 14):

By being explicit you are explicitly showing your intent.

By relying on something implicit you could have 2 cases: 1) You intended it, 2) You forgot it.

Comment: But why would it matter which of those 2 cases it was? *"A difference that makes no difference is no difference."*

Comment: @gnovice: Because if you have #2 "You forgot" then maybe you would have put a return value of 1 there instead.

Comment: A value of 1 generally indicates an error or abnormal termination. The OP is specifically asking about `return 0` vs. no `return 0` (i.e. a successful return). Forgetting to handle errors is a separate issue altogether. If I saw code without an explicit `return 0`, I wouldn't instantly think "they completely forgot about errors".

Comment: @gnovice: Precisely my point.   A value of 1 generally indicates an error.  Anyway I don't want to argue so feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Misunderstanding. There's simply no reason to, and if someone doesn't know that they'll add `return 0;`.

Answer (score 4):

Just because your *code* complies with the standard, who says your code is going to be run through a compliant *compiler*?  Believe it or not, people do use compilers besides just recent versions of GCC and Visual C++.

And of course there's the explicit intent thing that everyone else has mentioned.

Comment: Do you know of a compiler that will choke without it?

Comment: No, but I haven't tested every compiler in use today, either.

Comment: Eh, well if a compiler chokes on it, it's probably time to ditch the compiler.

Comment: Fair, but some people in some fields (military and automotive come to mind) don't have the luxury of just updating their tools whenever they feel like it.

Comment: You can't always ditch the compiler - you might need a specifix compiler for an old, or embedded platform.

Comment: I agree, sometimes you "need" an old compiler. But I think that's arguing for a corner case, and doesn't apply as a reason for the general programmer.

Comment: I agree with @GMan on this one. Respecting non-compliant compilers takes a lot of effort and yields little back. Do it if you must; otherwise don't.

Answer (score 3):

It makes behavior of the code explicit.

Answer (score 3):

- Makes it clear to other programmers that you didn't just forget to put the return statement there.
- Some compilers may issue a warning if you don't return anything.
- Shows explicitly what the function returns.
- Many programmers don't know about this rule.

Comment: "Some compilers may issue a warning if you don't return anything." Compiler is wrong, and you are correct in that case :)

Comment: Does it really matter if you are right and the compiler is wrong?  In most cases compiler warnings are unacceptable even if you are "technically" right.  Especially since the compiler warning is a good indication the compiler is not compliant with the implicit return 0.

Comment: I wouldn't say most. It *can* happen, sure, we've all seen it. But I'm willing to bet most warnings on issued on situations where the code is actually wrong.

Comment: @GMan: I didn't say that most compiler warnings /are/ issued on correct code. I said that most warnings /can/ be issued on correct code. It may only happen in a small percentage of cases for each warning though.

Answer (score 3):

Because some people don't know. Not necessarily the people who wrote that code (although that's also possible), but some people out there. Explicitly writing `return 0;` is being nice to them.

Also, as a convention it makes the language more uniform, which aesthetically is important to at least me.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is how they did it 30 years ago. It is more of a convention IMO.

Comment: @Juan Personally I don't write `return 0` at the end of `main`, I am just answering the question of why do we see it although it is not necessary.

Comment: I know, all I'm saying is that doing something because that's how they did it 30 years ago is more of a reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I often do it because I often compile code for straight C, so I either type it in out of habit or because the snippet I created `main()` from has the explicit return. There's no reason to remove it, so it usually stays.

Then again, there are times when I won't bother typing it in (maybe I realized I didn't need it) or I may have used a different snippet.